# Android Dagger2 error: @javax.inject.Named("BaseUrl") java.lang.String is bound multiple times

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm trying some things with Dagger2 but still difficult to understand..

I would like to use 2 services in 2 classes, SplashActivity and HomeActivity.
Services depends on NetModule because i would like reuse retrofit and okhttpclient provides.

Here is my NetModule :

```
@Module
public class NetModule {
    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(@Named("BaseUrl") String baseUrl, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        } else {
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        }

        return logging;
    }

    @Provides
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor, @Named("ConnectTimeoutMs") int connectTimeoutMs, @Named("ReadTimeoutMs") int readTimeoutMs) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .connectTimeout(connectTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(readTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
    }
}
```

StaticDataModule and StatusModule, it's 2 differents API so they use NetModule :

```
@Module(includes = NetModule.class)
public class StaticDataModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    StaticDataService provideStaticDataService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RetrofitStaticDataService(retrofit);
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("BaseUrl")
    String provideBaseUrl() {
        return "http://url_static.com";
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("ConnectTimeoutMs")
    int provideConnectTimeoutMs() {
        return 5000;
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("ReadTimeoutMs")
    int provideReadTimeoutMs() {
        return 5000;
    }
}

@Module(includes = NetModule.class)
public class StatusModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    StatusService provideStatusService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RetrofitStatusService(retrofit);
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("BaseUrl")
    String provideBaseUrl() {
        return "http://url_status.com";
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("ConnectTimeoutMs")
    int provideConnectTimeoutMs() {
        return 5000;
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("ReadTimeoutMs")
    int provideReadTimeoutMs() {
        return 5000;
    }
}
```

And i build them in this component :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, StaticDataModule.class, StatusModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(SplashActivity splashActivity);
    void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);
}
```

I obtain this error : @javax.inject.Named("BaseUrl") java.lang.String is bound multiple times.
I understand my error, dagger dont know who provide between StaticData baseUrl and Status baseUrl.

I tried to make 2 components, StaticDataComponent and StatusComponent, but i can't inject both in the same activity.

I tried to extends NetModule in StaticDataModule and StatusModule, and give parameters with constructor, but multiple bounds error was on retrofit provide.

So i don't know how to reuse NetModule with differents parameters in 2 modules, if someone has an example it should really help me.

Thanks !

Comment: The easiest thing, you can do: change names to the StatusBaseUrl and StaticBaseUrl

Comment: But in NetModule for baseUrl what i need ? i must write @Named("Something") no ?

Comment: Or no, use the same names, but don't include NetModule as dependency. Use for one component (NetModule + status module), for second component (NetModule + static module)

Comment: Yeah, this worked to create 2 services, but the problem with this are inject. If i make NetModule+StatusModule to inject in MainActivity and NetModule+StaticModule to inject in MainActivity it's not working, 2 components can't inject same class.. that's my problem =( or maybe there is a way for component to take inject of parent ?

Comment: When you meet such situation, it means that you better have to rework your architecture :) Solution can be, that you do not inject as usual, but provide as method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include NetModule.class as dependency to your modules, just include them separately in the component.

```
@Module(includes = NetModule.class)
public class StaticDataModule {
```

to

```
@Module
public class StaticDataModule {
```

And then use like this:

```
@Component(modules = {
    NetModule.class, StaticDataModule.class
}) public interface FirstComponent {
  void inject(WhateverYouWantActivity activity);
}

@Component(modules = {
    NetModule.class, StatusModule.class
}) public interface FirstComponent {
  void inject(WhateverYouWantSecondActivity activity);
}
```

If you have to inject into the same activity, you better rework your architecture, but if you still want to do this, you can get rid of inject method, and add something like this:

```
@Component(modules = { /* your modules */ }) public interface YourComponent {

  Retrofit getRetrofit();

  OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient();
}
```

And use it accordingly:

```
retrofit = yourComponentBuiltByDagger.getRetrofit();
```

Instead of:

```
@Inject Retrofit retrofit;
```

Comment: Ok thx i'll do that. Maybe i can try to make StaticDataModule and StatusModule with their own provideRetrofit with differents name, like ur previous anwser. The only probleme with that, i must redefine provideRetrofit for each api service who use retrofit..

Comment: You inject two retrofits to the one activity?

Comment: I just want avoid to link retrofit to activity, if i want to change retrofit by another library i would like to change only that in module.

Comment: @Lyofen you don't need retrofit for real, inject ApiService interface

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found a simple solution, my architecture was bad. Now i need only one module, and retrofit is not provide, he is build inside StaticData and Status implementation :

```
@Module
public class NetModule {
    @Provides
    HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        } else {
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        }

        return logging;
    }

    @Provides
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .connectTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    StaticDataService provideStaticDataService(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new RetrofitStaticDataService("http://url_1.com",okHttpClient);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    StatusService provideStatusService(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new RetrofitStatusService("http://url_2.com",okHttpClient);
    }

}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(SplashActivity splashActivity);
    void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);
}
```

Retrofit objects are only in retrofit implementation class, so if i need change retrofit by another library i have just to change new RetrofitStaticDataService() by new AnotherStaticDataService().

Thanks for help Anton.